# Tooltip position is not changing (D3)

Tags: javascript, d3.js, charts, tooltip, cursor-position

I'm trying to create a tooltip that will appear next to the dot that is representing the data.
This is the complete project: https://codepen.io/imestin/pen/rNOpdae?editors=0110

This is the code that is supposed to position the tooltip:

```
var mousemove = function(d) {
    Tooltip
      .html("Time: " + d.Time + "<br>Time in seconds: " + d.Seconds + "<br>Year: " + d.Year + "<br>" + d.Doping)
      .attr("data-year", () => {
        return d.Year;
      })
      .style("left", (d3.mouse(this)[0]+70) + "px")
      .style("top", (d3.mouse(this)[1]) + "px")
```

No matter what I do, I can even write fix numbers there like 70, the position of the tooltip is not changing.
I'm doing the tooltip according to [this](https://www.d3-graph-gallery.com/graph/interactivity_tooltip.html#template) tutorial, where it is working.

I don't understand what am I doing wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add this css rule:

```
.tooltip {
  display: inline;
  position: fixed;
}
```

You can improve the code making this change

```
var mousemove = function(d) {
    Tooltip
      .html("Time: " + d.Time + "<br>Time in seconds: " + d.Seconds + "<br>Year: " + d.Year + "<br>" + d.Doping)
      .attr("data-year", () => {
        return d.Year;
      })
      .style("left", (d3.mouse(this)[0]+ 20) + "px")
      .style("top", (d3.mouse(this)[1]) + "px")
  }
```

The problem is not the d3.js code, but the css rules. In your code the tooltip div works like a block element so it uses the full width of the page. It also use a wrong position rule. For css position this resource https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_position should be helpful.
It works better.

Comment: yes, this solved the problem, thank you!

this is working link for the w3schools resource, .asp was missing: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_position.asp